# keep track of increment and decrement of values in python tuple

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, list, tuples

I have a list like below,

```
list_ = [('a', 5), ('a', 6), ('a', 8), ('a', 2), ('a', 5), ('a', 9), ('a', 10),
             ('b', 3), ('b', 7), ('b', 6), ('b', 2), ('b', 6), ('b', 5), ('b', 10)]
```

I want to do the following operation.
If the values in tuple increase i must keep track of increment, if it decrease i must keep track of decrement and finally i need the sum of both.

```
# for key 'a' for example
# increment      decrement
#       1             6
#       2
#       3
#       4
#       1
# Hence total increment is 11 and decrement is 6
# so I need the result like this. ('a', (11, 6))
```

I did like this to get the increment for example, but not working.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in list_:
    d[k].append(v)

counter1 = 0

for key, value in d.items():
  for i in range(len(value)):
    try:
      if value[i] < value[i+1]:
        s = value[i+1] - value[i]
        counter1 +=s
    except:
      pass


print(counter1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def incdec(lst):
    d = {}
    for k, v in lst:
        try:
            last = d[k]
        except KeyError:
            d[k] = [0, 0, v]
        else:
            delta = v - last[2]
            last[2] = v
            last[delta < 0] += abs(delta)
    return [(k, (v[0], v[1])) for k, v in d.items()]
```

It works on iterable `lst` (doesn't collect data, remember only increments and decrements, not whole data).

`d` is dict of temporary list, where [0] is increment, [1] decrement [2] last value.

`last[delta < 0]` is a trick, because `bool` is kind of `int`, then in this case you can address [0] (inc) or [1] (dec). I know, it's not readable too much. You can change it to `if / else`.

Last line return data in required format (inc and dec, without [2] – last value).

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame([('a', 5), ('a', 6), ('a', 8), ('a', 2), ('a', 5), ('a', 9), ('a', 10),
             ('b', 3), ('b', 7), ('b', 6), ('b', 2), ('b', 6), ('b', 5), ('b', 10)], columns=['col1','col2'])


for value,tmp_df  in df.groupby('col1'):

    increase = tmp_df['col2']-tmp_df['col2'].shift(1)
    positive = increase[increase>0].sum()
    negative = increase[increase<0].sum()
    print ((value, (positive, negative)))
```

Comment: nice creative use of dataframe, but I think OP wants `abs(negative)`